# Configure dnsmasq to passthrough search domain to LXC guest? (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: domain-name-system, lxc, dnsmasq, containers

Our network relies on DHCP tags to route clients to the correct upstream hosts without having to know the FQDN of those hosts. We use `dnsmasq` to set tags for clients by MAC address and then we push different search domains to the clients based on the tag. For example, we have these two lines in `dnsmasq.conf`:

```
dhcp-option=tag:foo,option:domain-search,foo.company.net
dhcp-host=00:11:22:33:44:55,foo-client,set:foo
```

Here, when `foo-client` tries to access any unqualified hosts, it will try looking at `<unqualified-hostname>.foo.company.net`.

Some of the client machines are also running services inside of an LXC container. The container gets its networking information assigned by a local instance of `dnsmasq` running on the LXC host, which is the default method for DNS/DHCP of LXC guests. The LXC guest then gets an IP address on a local NAT network.

The trouble comes from our tagging scheme. The LXC guests don't get the search domain pushed to them because they're not receiving DCHP from our main network-wide DHCP server. The LXC guests can ping IP addresses on the wider network, but DNS resolution with the search domain fails. If I manually set the correct search domain, then resolution works as expected.

Is there a way to pass through that search domain from the host to the guest?

Note, we are NOT running `lxd`.

Comment: Remember that it's best practice to use FQDNs everywhere. The search domain is not reliable for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't find an exact solution to this, but I did find a workaround. Basically LXC can run a script on the guest before bringing the network up. This configuration option is called `lxc.network.script.up`. I used this feature to copy DNS information from the host:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONTAINER=$1
SECTION=$2
OPERATION=$3
NAMESERVER=$(grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf  | sed 's/^nameserver //g')
SEARCHDOMAIN=$(grep search /etc/resolv.conf  | sed 's/^search //g')

cat > /var/lib/lxc/$CONTAINER/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces <<EOF

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
dns-search $SEARCHDOMAIN
dns-nameservers $NAMESERVER
EOF
```

I placed this script in `/var/lib/lxc/guest/setup-dns.sh` and added the following line to `/var/lib/lxc/guest/config`:

```
lxc.network.script.up = /var/lib/lxc/guest/setup-dns.sh
```

After doing these steps, the guest comes up and has DNS and search path options properly set.